# Download File With $_POST (PHP & HTML)

Tags: php, html

Ok, i'm back once again :), but with a new problem!

I'm trying to make a button, when clicked, it will do the `location.href` to my download.php

witching the code is:

```
<?
ob_start();
require_once 'includes/db.php';
require_once 'includes/init.php';
?>
<?php

     $file = "logs/".$_SESSION['username'].".txt";

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

My other code witching initializes the button to download the .txt file:

```
<?php 
        if (isset($_POST['clearBtn']))
        {
             ?>
               < location.href = 'download.php'>
              <?
            echo '<div class="nNote nSuccess hideit"><p><strong>SUCCESS: </strong>Logs have been downloaded</p></div>';
        }
        ?>
        <div class="widget">
          <div class="title"><img src="images/icons/dark/frames.png" alt="" class="titleIcon" /><h6>Logs</h6><form action = "" method="post" class="form">
          <input type="submit" style="margin-top: 4px; margin-right:4px;" value="Download Logs" name="clearBtn" class="dblueB logMeIn" />
```

How do i make this part work:

```
          ?>
          < location.href = 'download.php'>
          <?
```

Thank you to anyone who can answer this, i know this is probubly an easy question, but i can't find an answer any where, Thanks :)

Comment: What is the purpose of 'witching' here?

Comment: `< a href="download.php">...</a>` ?

Answer (score 3):

An `<a>` tag has no such property named `location.href`. You're thinking of javascript.

Use `href`:

```
<a href="download.php">Text</a>
```

Comment: First step: Don't download the file, just render the `$file` name you've calculated. Make sure that file exists, first.

Comment: @RepairServices What happens? Do you get an empty page? If so, it seems like your file does not exist. Try using `var_dump(file_exists($file));`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one.

```
<a href="Javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.location.href='download.php'"> Text </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To Automatically download the file do:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['clearBtn'])): ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">window.location.href='download.php';</script>
  <div class="nNote nSuccess hideit"><p><strong>SUCCESS: </strong>Logs have been downloaded</p></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: no, i want it to go to download.php with out opening it, like in the background, and also download the .txt

Comment: I have not tested your download script. It's looking good. Your download should start in the background.